# How to resolve expects parameter '@id', which was not supplied

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I am developing wpf application and i need to insert and update data . I have insert data successfully but when am execute update am getting error like expects parameter '@id', which was not supplied. I have give all the things properly but still am getting same error

I have given my code below

stored procedure code

```
Alter procedure Updatedata  
(  
   @id VARCHAR(10),  
   @name VARCHAR(10),  
   @address VARCHAR(10),  
   @city varchar(20),  
   @state VARCHAR(20),
   @country varchar(10)

)  
AS  
BEGIN 
update Employee set  name= @name, address = @address, city = @city , state= @state, country = @country where id=@id 
END
```

C# code

```
private void btn_Update_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var con = new SqlConnection(strConnString);

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Updatedata", con);
        con.Open();
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(@"id", txt_id.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(@"name", txt_name.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@address", txt_address.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@city", txt_city.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@state", txt_state.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@country", txt_country.Text);
        int row = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        con.Close();
    }
```

Comment: **`@"id"`** <> **`@id`**    Same for name

Comment: You have the same syntax problem with name too.

Comment: @lad2025 - I may have laughed to hard when I saw the error :D

Comment: You should also change the `cmd` to state that it's a stored proc rather than text.

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is here:

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(@"id", txt_id.Text);
```

It should be

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", txt_id.Text);
```

While you're at it, change this too:

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(@"name", txt_name.Text);
```

to

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", txt_name.Text);
```

You will also need to set the `CommandType` of `cmd` to be `StoredProcedure`.

By default, it's executing it as text.

```
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
```

Comment: Same problem for name.

Comment: I have changed everything but still am getting same issue

Comment: @NagarajanM - as I said in the comments, you also need to `cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure` (or similar - free typing without intellisense)

Comment: @MightyBadaboom see edited answer

Comment: @NagarajanM did that work?